# Hide file update date in Android Studio in Project Navigator

Tags: android-studio

I've accidentally enabled these 'last updated date' in Android Studio Project navigator and I am unable to find that setting in Preferences. How to turn it off and see just file names?

[image: Screen]

Comment: Is there anything like "Details in Tree View" setting in View | Appearances

Answer (score 10):

You can disable/enable it in View -> Appearance -> Descriptions in Tree Views
(big thanks to Aniket Kariya

[image]